# Wordpress page and posts - Add tick box to insert code into header

Tags: php, wordpress, meta

I have a Wordpress site and I'm looking at include a little tick box next to each post and each page.

When ticked, this box will add the following meta line to the header of that page:

```
<meta name="meetandengage-premium-content" content="true">
```

So essentially it allows the user to mark a post as premium content. This in turn allows the guys that look after the main server platform and all of the infrastructure to password protect these pages.

I'm a bit stuck as where to start, I can find ways to add a tick box on the post and page editor, I could also essentially do that using Advanced Custom Fields too... but once the tick box is there, I need to apply something that says: If ticked, display line, else don't display line, I guess?

I'm finding it difficult to find any info as I don't really know what to search for...

I'm not sure what the page or posts list pages are called?? (screenshot attached). If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Adding the line of meta info is the ONLY way I am able to do this so I cannot use any 3rd party password protect plugins :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to find a solution to this - Pretty simple - I added the tick meta box using Advanced Custom Fields and then used the following code to display my meta tag if the box is ticked:

```
<?php 
        $selected = get_field('premium_content');
            if( in_array('Yes', $selected) ) {
                echo '<meta name="meetandengage-premium-content" content="true">';
        }
    ?>
```